# How can I add two StackLayouts one on top of the other?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I tried to do this:

```
<ViewCell>
    <StackLayout Padding="0,15,0,0" HeightRequest="300" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
        <chart:SfChart x:Name="chart1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        </chart:SfChart>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Padding="0,15,0,0" HeightRequest="300" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
        <chart:SfChart x:Name="chart2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        </chart:SfChart>
    </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```

But only the second chart appears.

What I would like is to see the two charts, one on top of the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ViewCell accepts only one element as child.
Just wrap your stacks in another StackLayout:

```
<ViewCell>
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Padding="0,15,0,0" HeightRequest="300" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
            <chart:SfChart x:Name="chart1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            </chart:SfChart>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Padding="0,15,0,0" HeightRequest="300" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
            <chart:SfChart x:Name="chart2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            </chart:SfChart>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you want better layout performance from your ViewCells, consider making use of a Xamarin.Forms Grid with two rows and one column.